# PHP Session Variable value is changing unexpectedly

Tags: php

I have my page validate.php with the following codes :

```
if (session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE){
    session_start(); // Init session data
}
 if (empty($_SESSION['variableto'])) {
        $_SESSION['variableto'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
    }

    if (isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['column'])) {
           if (hash_equals($_SESSION['variableto'], $_GET['name']) &&  $_GET['status']=='YES_OK') {
          echo 'validated';
      }
    }else{
       header('Location: https://externaldomain.com/check.php?redirect=mydomain.com/validate.php&name='.$_SESSION['variableto'] );
        exit();
    }
```

The External domain redirects back to my page but with 2 parameters: **name** which is the token I generated stored in the session variable $_SESSION['variableto']  and **column**. The value of the parameter name is the one that I am going to verify against the session variable again when the external domain redirect the user back to my application.

The problem is when the user get redirected on my application if I check the $_SESSION['variableto'] value I am finding it has changed, it is different from what was sent to the external web app. The change happens without the user being logged out.

I am confused, is there something wrong with my code? Why is the session value getting changed yet the user is not logged out (I think session variable get cleaned when the user logs out) ?

Comment: So, when I request `validate.php?name=HexFromRedirect&status=YES_OK`, am I validated on your page?

Comment: Hold on though, if you have the logged in user before redirect they are using cookie auth. Then when they come back wouldn't you want to just check if the user is logged in and get the user id now you have a more reliable way of verifying, if the cookie auth was spoofed then basically you have much bigger problems to worry about. Or are you using the session variable as your only way of identifying a logged in user?

Comment: It may also just be your .htaccess redirecting from www. to non www that is known to mess with sessions. As well as the user left on example.com and retirned to www.example.com

Comment: When you request validate.php?name=HexFromRedirect&status=YES_OK you will not because the session variable value is different from Hex yet it is supposed to be Hex since you have not logged out yet. The validation is not from logging in the user it is for validating something information that the user has provided... So I am using a third party for validating the data... the third party is redirecting the user back to my website so to avoid CRSF I am using the $_SESSION['variableto'] as token

Comment: @rifi2k what is the solution in that case if it is the .htaccess ?

Comment: I meant when it will work as expected... the validation will depend on the information my browser (or bot) sends when redirecting back to your site? As a first point of start you should monitor the line `$_SESSION['variableto'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));` (xdebug or logging etc.) When does it actually get called? Do use a known constant token and check what you get back from 3rd party.

Comment: I could imagine that a proper 3rd party validation works like that: you generate a token, the 3rd party generates a token and your server has to request the 3rd party site directly if both tokens together are considered as validated. That's why I was asking if I am validated when I just spoof the last request asserting "Oh yes, I have beed validated".

Comment: Another approach of 3rd party validation could be that you have negotiated some secret, e.g. a private / public key pair, and the communication via the visitor as man in the middle is authenticated by some kind of encryption process.

Comment: Remove your htaccess to see if it fixes it is the easiest way to tell if that redirect is the problem

Comment: I don't have htaccess but still the issue is there.